# window.location redirect doesn't work on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why `window.location` does not work on some of **IE8** browsers? I tried on 10 computers with IE8, 8 of them work 2 of them don't work. This is the script I'm using to redirect the browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
sublimevideo.ready(function(){
    sublimevideo.prepareAndPlay('video1');
  sublimevideo.onEnd(function(sv){
    window.location = 'http://www.site.com.au/register';
  });
});          
</script>
```

Comment: Try `window.location.href = 'yourLocation'`

Comment: Did you try multiple times on each computer?

Comment: Thanks. i tried many times. 8/10 works everytime there are 2 that didnt work. Out of those 2, i updated java on 1, and it worked. Im  trying to find a way to redirect with old java updates.

Comment: @Austin sorry. can you please tell me how to accept answers? I cant find it anywhere!

Comment: No javascript errors? Put it in try and catch(error) and alert the error.

Comment: Not a problem, just click the check box next to the answer you feel best helped solve your problem.

Comment: Do you have any Java applets on your page?

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to direct the browser to navigate to a new page is to use [`location.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Methods):

```
location.assign('http://example.com');
```

Comment: Thanks. But it needs a java update. The computers with old java updates didn't do anything.

Comment: how "old" of the java are we talking about? Does it work in IE7 and IE8 ?

Comment: Neither location.assign or window.location work for me in IE 8.0.7601.17514.

Answer (score 0):

Please try **window.location.href="<URL>";**

You can do sample code bin on http://codebins.com/ and check result as you want.